# An easier way to prove this

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f\in C^1[a,b]$, and $f''$ exists on $(a,b)$. Show that, for any $c\in (a,b)$, there is $\xi\in(a,b)$ s.t.

$$\frac{1}{c-b}\left(\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right)=\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}$$

One very elegant but not trivial way is by considering the following function:

$$g(t)=\text{det}\begin{pmatrix}f(t)&t^2&t&1\\
f(c)&c^2&c&1\\
f(a)&a^2&a&1\\
f(b)&b^2&b&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

one can see that $g\in C^1[a,b]$ and $g''$ exists on $(a,b)$, moreover we have $g(a)=g(b)=g(c)=0$, thus by applying Rolle's theorem twice, we can get what we want.

I think this method is very elegant, but quite hard to come up with. I am trying to find an easier and more elementary approach, such as applying Taylor's theorem and mean value theorem to $f$ or a function that can be much easier to come  up with, but it seems that these approaches did not work very well.

Does anyone have some idea about an easier way to prove this?

Comment: Even if we use taylor's mean value theorem or successive divided differences it's going to amount the same thing, (solving/eliminating a bunch of linear relations that ultimately is same as dealing with $g(t)$). Apart from that I have no idea at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function $h(t)$ on the closed interval $[a,b]$ as

$$
h(t){}:={}\left\{\begin{array}{cl}f^{'}(a)&;\mbox{for }\,t{}={}a\\&\\\dfrac{f(t)-f(a)}{t-a}&;\mbox{for }\,t{}\in{}(a,b]\end{array}\right.
$$

Then, $h(t)$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous on $[a,b]$. Consequently, by the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), for $c\in(a,b)$, there exists $\theta\in(c,b)$ such that

$$
\dfrac{h(c)-h(b)}{c-b}{}={}h^{'}(\theta)\,.
$$

In addition, by [Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), there exists $\xi\in(a,\theta)$ such that
$$
h^{'}(\theta){}={}\dfrac{(\theta-a)f^{'}(\theta)-f(\theta)+f(a)}{(\theta-a)^2}{}={}\dfrac{1}{2}f^{''}(\xi)\,.
$$

> Therefore, for $c\in(a,b)$, there exists $\xi\in(a,b)$ such that
> $$
> \dfrac{h(c)-h(b)}{c-b}{}={}\dfrac{1}{2}f^{''}(\xi)\,.
> $$

Comment: Very elegant answer. +1 However it is slightly hard to note the use of Taylor theorem for $h'(\theta)$. This Taylor series is about the point $\theta$ and $f(a)$ is being expressed as a power series in $(a - \theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $\lambda:=c-a$, $\mu:=b-a$ and notice that $\lambda-\mu=c-b$. 
Define $g(x):=\frac{1}{\lambda}f(a+\lambda x)+\frac{1}{\mu}f(a+\mu x)$.
By Cauchy theorem
$$\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{g(1)-g(0)}{1^2-0^2}
=\frac{f'(a+\lambda\zeta)-f'(a+\mu\zeta)}{2\zeta}$$
for some $\zeta\in(0,1)$ and by Lagrange theorem the last difference quotient equals
$$\frac{(\lambda\zeta-\mu\zeta)f''(\xi)}{2\zeta}=(c-b)\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}$$
for some $\xi\in(a,b)$. (We interpreted $1$ as $1^2-0^2$ instead of $1-0$ so as to kill the factor $\zeta$ coming from the numerator of the difference quotient.)

**Remark:** If $f\in C^2([a,b])$, one gets a very natural solution by writing the difference quotients as integrals: $\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}=\int_0^1 f'(a+\lambda t)\,dt$ and $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\int_0^1 f'(a+\mu t)\,dt$, so that

$$\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\int_0^1 \Big(f'(a+\lambda t)-f'(a+\mu t)\Big)\,dt=\int_0^1\int_{\mu t}^{\lambda t}f''(a+s)\,ds\,dt$$

and finally

$$\frac{1}{c-b}\left(\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^1 2t f''\Big(a+\mu t+(\lambda-\mu)s\Big)\,ds\,dt$$

But $\int_0^1\int_0^1 2t\,ds\,dt=1$, so the last double integral involving $f''$ lies in the convex hull of all the values of $f''$, i.e. it belongs to the image of $f''$ (since it is an interval, thus convex).

Comment: Another very good answer and a smart use of the Cauchy's theorem with $f(x) = x^{2}$ in the denominator. +1